# KOTH: Number fight

Tags: number, king-of-the-hill

### Number fight game

- **Setup**

Each ai is given a random number from 1 to 100. The starting number is the average of these two numbers.

- **Gameplay**

Each ai knowing its own target, the opposite target and the current number, chooses which function to apply to the current number.

- **WIN conditions**

The first ai that reaches its number wins.

- **Scoring details**

The score is given in a tournament: each ai will fight all the other ais and it will get a score equal to the average of the points scored against the opponents.

---

The controller script is limited to Python-only functions, but if you can provide a controller that allows other languages your are welcome.

Controller script for reference:

```
import random

def increment(a): return a + 1
def decrement(a): return a - 1
def double(a)   : return 2 * a
def halve(a)    : return a // 2
def square(a)   : return a**2
def sqrt(a)     : return int(a**0.5)
def nop(a)      : return a

ALLOWED_FUNCTIONS = [increment, decrement, double, halve,
                     square, sqrt, nop]


def number_obtainer_master(ai_1,ai_2,logging):
    """
    Handles a number-fight game between two bots.

    SETUP: Each one of the 2 ais gets a random number from 1 to 100
    as its target. The starting number is the average of the two numbers.

    GAMEPLAY: Each ai should try to reach its goal before the opponent,
    the first ai that reaches its number wins.
    Note: After 500 turns, if noone has won, the game is declared drawn.
    """
    target_numbers = [random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100)]
    starting_number = sum(target_numbers) // 2
    number = starting_number
    if logging:
        print("""The match is about to start, the contending AIs are:
{} - whose target is {}
{} - whose target is {}
The starting number is: {}\n\n""".format(ai_1.__name__,target_numbers[0],
                                     ai_2.__name__,target_numbers[1],
                                     starting_number))
    for turn in range(500):
        if logging:
            print("""\n         --- Turn: {} --- """.format(turn))
        ais = [ai_1,ai_2]
        for ai in ais:
            if ai == ai_1:
                ai_function = ai(target_numbers[0],target_numbers[1],number)
            else:
                ai_function = ai(target_numbers[1],target_numbers[0],number)
            if ai_function not in ALLOWED_FUNCTIONS:
                raise ValueError("Invalid function was returned")
            number = ai_function(number)
            if logging:
                print("{} chose {}: the number now is: {}".format(
                ai.__name__,ai_function.__name__,number))
            if number in target_numbers:
                if logging:
                    print("{} won.\n\n".format(ai.__name__))
                return 1 if number == target_numbers[0] else 0
    if logging:
        print("After 500 turns the match is not ended yet: tie.\n\n")
    return 0.5

def compare_strength(ai_1,ai_2,accuracy):
    """
    Returns how many times ai_1 is better than ai_2.
    Harder than it should be to compensate advantage of going first.
    """
    ai_1_score = sum([number_obtainer_master(ai_1,ai_2,False) for _ in range(accuracy//2)])
    ai_1_score = sum([ 1 - number_obtainer_master(ai_2,ai_1,False) for _ in range(accuracy//2)])
    return ai_1_score / accuracy # 1 means perfect

def tournament(ais,accuracy):
    """
    Lets each ai fight all the other ais and returns a nicely sorted leaderboard.
    """
    scores = []
    for ai in ais:
        score = sum ( (compare_strength(ai,opponent,accuracy) for opponent in ais if opponent != ai) ) / len(ais)
        scores.append((ai.__name__,score))
    return sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)

## Default simple ais

def sleeping_ai(self_target,opposite_target,current_number):
    return nop

def simplistic_ai(self_target,opposite_target,current_number):
    return increment if current_number < self_target else decrement

def cleverish_ai(self_target,opposite_target,current_number):
    target,n = self_target,current_number
    if n*2 < target:
        return double
    elif n//2 == target:
        return halve
    elif n**2 == target:
        return square
    return increment if current_number < self_target else decrement

def increment_ai(self_target,opposite_target,current_number):
    return increment

## Partecipants ais


print(tournament([sleeping_ai,simplistic_ai,
                 cleverish_ai,increment_ai],200))
```

Comment: You should probably describe what functions are available and what they do (in English, not in code). Also, you should describe how you will provide input and how you will expect output (again, in English). You'll have a much higher participation rate if we don't have to dive into your Python.

Comment: Since this is a perfect information game with very limited game state, I believe there is an *unbeatable* algorithm to this. That generally doesn't make for the best KotH, but it may be better suited as another type of challenge.

Comment: I voted for closing. But not because it is unclear what you're asking. This type is simply not suited for KOTH. Every 'good' ai will have a line in it, to only play a move, where the opponent can't finish in one turn. Therefore each battle will end tied, except the first player can reach the number in one move.